# Automounting not working correctly for CIFS shares; weird results

Tags: linux, samba, automounting, autofs

I followed the guide on this page to get samba shares working via autofs:

http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs

**Servers and Configuration**

My Samba server (remote) is on a server named "mattserver" (that's its Windows server name). It has four shares, called "backup", "matt", "print", and "web". The Samba client (local) is named "bird".

My setup is very similar to the examples in the aforementioned tutorial, except for some differences:

- `/cifs /etc/auto.cifs --ghost` instead of `/cifs /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=60` in `/etc/auto.master`
- `uid=1000,gid=1000` instead of `uid=user,gid=users` in `/etc/auto.cifs`

Here's my `/etc/auto.master`:

```
matt@bird:~ $ cat /etc/auto.master
/cifs /etc/auto.cifs --ghost
```

Here's my `/etc/auto.cifs`:

```
matt@bird:~ $ cat /etc/auto.cifs
#!/bin/bash
key="$1"
credfile="/etc/auto.smb.$key"
mountopts="-fstype=cifs,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=1000,gid=1000"
smbclientopts=""
for P in /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin
do
    if [ -x $P/smbclient ]
        then
        SMBCLIENT=$P/smbclient
        break
    fi
done
[ -x $SMBCLIENT ] || exit 1
if [ -e "$credfile" ]
then
    mountopts=$mountopts",credentials=$credfile"
    smbclientopts="-A "$credfile
else
    smbclientopts="-N"
fi
$SMBCLIENT $smbclientopts -gL $key 2>/dev/null \
    | awk -v key="$key" -v opts="$mountopts" -F'|' -- '
        BEGIN   { ORS=""; first=1 }
        /Disk/  { if (first) { print opts; first=0 };
        gsub(/ /, "\\ ", $2);
        sub(/\$/, "\\$", $2);
        print " \\\n\t /" $2, "://" key "/" $2 }
        END     { if (!first) print "\n"; else exit 1 }
        '
```

So here's what I get when I call `/etc/auto.cifs` directly:

```
matt@bird:~ $ sudo bash /etc/auto.cifs mattserver
-fstype=cifs,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/etc/auto.smb.mattserver \
            /print\$ ://mattserver/print\$ \
            /matt ://mattserver/matt \
            /web ://mattserver/web \
            /backup ://mattserver/backup
```

So far, so good, I think.

**Testing**

When I try to access the `/cifs` directory, I should get one directory called `mattserver`, right? I did put the `--ghost` option in there. I don't get anything though:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs
total 0
```

When I access the server directory, I get a list of shares but it's screwed up:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs/mattserver
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver/web: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver/print$: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver/matt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver/backup: No such file or directory
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? backup
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? matt
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? print$
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? web
```

When I try to access an actual share, I get nothing:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs/mattserver/web
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver/web: No such file or directory
```

As a test, I added a line to `/etc/hosts` for `mattserver`.

Still no ghosting:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs
total 0
```

When I try accessing the server directory again, I no longer get a list of shares:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs/mattserver
ls: cannot access /cifs/mattserver: No such file or directory
```

But when I access an actual share, I get full access:

```
matt@bird:~ $ ls -l /cifs/mattserver/web
[correct listing of files -- removed]
```

I should be able to rely on broadcasting and I shouldn't need to have anything in /etc/hosts (right?). Broadcasting is working:

```
matt@bird:~ $ nmblookup mattserver
querying mattserver on 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.2 mattserver<00>
```

**Problems**

- When I try and access a list of servers by calling `ls -l /cifs`, I get nothing.
- When I try and access a list of shares by calling `ls -l /cifs/mattserver`, I get a screwed up list (see above).
- I can't get a share mounted without adding an entry for the servername to `/etc/hosts`. I don't want to rely on a kludgy entry in `/etc/hosts`.

What are my options here?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a way around this issue?

Comment: I don't think so, it was always always flaky for me. Abandoned effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has said:  "Abandoned effort. – Matt Alexander Dec 3 '14 at 3:40"