# Issues accessing CIFS share directories

Tags: linux, centos, automounting, autofs, cifs

**Disclaimer 1:** *[Crossposted from Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/538227/issues-accessing-cifs-share-directories) because there was no activity over there.*

**Disclaimer 2:** *This question is similar to [Automounting not working correctly for CIFS shares; weird results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/automounting-not-working-correctly-for-cifs-shares-weird-results) but not exactly the same.*

**The Setup:**

Running CentOS most recent stable (6.4) connecting to CIFS share from EMC VNXe SAN.

Using AutoFS configured using this method: http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=240811

Synopsis of config:

> 1. Install autofs
> 2. Comment out entire /etc/auto.master
> 3. Create new /etc/auto.cifs file with contents similar to auto.smb (full contents at link above)
> 4. *chmod 755 /etc/auto.cifs*
> 5. Add line /etc/auto.master: */mnt /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=0*
> 6. Create file /etc/auto.smb.fileserver01 with credentials: username=domain/username password=password (also tried without domain,
>      exact same symptoms)
> 7. *chmod 400 /etc/auto.smb.fileserver01*
> 8. Add fileserver01 to /etc/hosts

I have supplied AutoFS with a full Domain Admin account for initial build and testing.

**The Problem**

The CIFS share mounts in */mnt/fileserver01* and I can see the contents of the share's root directory, but when I try to navigate inside any of the directories I receive the message:

> bash: cd: /mnt/fileserver01/sharename: No such file or directory

There aren't any particular errors showing up inside */var/log/messages*.

*Note: I'm new to Linux server administration, dusting off 10-year-old weekend classes in Debian CLI, so for answers and questions please be explicit in what I need to enter into the terminal.*