# autofs cifs samba

Tags: samba, cifs, autofs

[Automounting not working correctly for CIFS shares; weird results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/automounting-not-working-correctly-for-cifs-shares-weird-results)

Base on the above question,
my issue is that my samba/cifs password do have '*' and '&' characters which point me to the lines:

```
if [ -e "$credfile" ]
then
    opts=$opts",credentials=$credfile"
    smbclientopts="-A "$credfile
```

what would be the correct way to escape the password? in the credfile

```
username='user'
password='*pass&word?Secure'
```

this way fail

```
username=user
password=\*pass\&word\?Secure
```

or fix the "     smbclientopts="-A "$credfile "

thanks for the comments.

**2020 update**:
clean pop-os install

```
> apt install samba autofs smbclient 
> sudo nano /etc/creds/<<host>> 
> sudo chmod rw-r-r /etc/creds/<<host>> 
> sudo nano /etc/auto.master ###edit: /smb auto.smb --timeout=300 
> sudo systemctl restart autofs.service
```

results:

```
> the ls /smb/<<host>> show all the shares 
> but ls /smb/<<host>>/<<share>> 
> ls -l /smb/ccollart/home 
> ls: cannot open directory '/smb/ccollart/home': No such file or directory
```

syslog:

```
> Feb  5 11:26:33 pop-os kernel: [10292.285802] CIFS: Attempting to mount //ccollart/home
> Feb  5 11:26:33 pop-os kernel: [10292.285816] Unable to determine destination address.
```

I then install winbind:

> sudo apt install libnss-winbind winbind

BTW, my local DNS do add searchdomain = localdomain and DNS do resolve IPv4 both "host" and "host.localdomain"

Comment: How did come to the conclusion that the linked question (closed without a resolution) references special characters in the credentials file? I have a few in mine (not yours, in particular) and didn't need to escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution was to install CIFS-UTILS,because the FS type is opts="-fstype=cifs"

> sudo apt install cifs-utils

but most of the tutorials that I follow doesn't include this step,maybe